# Does the use of auto keyword enable dynamic binding in C++?

Tags: c++

The following is the code snippet from geeksforgeeks to demonestrate early and late binding in C++.

```
// CPP Program to illustrate late binding
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
    
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void show() { cout<<" In Base \n"; }
};
    
class Derived: public Base
{
public:
    void show() { cout<<"In Derived \n"; }
};
    
int main(void)
{
    Base *bp = new Derived;
    bp->show(); // RUN-TIME POLYMORPHISM
    return 0;
}
```

We need to use the `virtual` keyword inorder to get polymorphism in C++. However if I remove the `virtual` keyword from the class Base and use `auto` keyword when I create an object(`auto *bp = new Derived;`) still get same result. How is it possible as auto variable is resolved at compile time?

Comment: `auto` is resolved at compile time.

Comment: ya I meant compile time thanks corrected.

Comment: `auto *bp = new Derived;` results in `bp` having type `Derived *` instead of `Base *` so no polymorphism is used.  Indeed in the `auto` version, `Base` might as well not exist at all.

Answer (score 5):

No, it does not. `auto` is deduced completely at compile-time, the same way as template arguments are.

So here `new Derived` has type `Derived*` and therefore the obvious type for `auto` be deduced to is `Derived`.

```
auto *bp = new Derived;
```

is here completely equivalent to

```
Derived *bp = new Derived;
```

and you can see that the "correct" `show` is called here only because the pointer is already a pointer to the derived class.

If you use `static_cast<Base*>(bp)->show()` to cast the pointer back to its base class first, then you will see that there is no runtime polymorphism without `virtual`.

Answer (score 2):

No, the `auto` keyword does not mean that anything is resolved at run time.  It's just a shorthand that tells the compiler to figure out what type should be put there.

When you write `auto * bg = new Derived;` is means the same thing as `Derived * bg = new Derived;`.  If you don't believe me, look at the error message your compiler gives you when you run this code:

```cpp
class Base {};
class Derived: public Base {};
    
int main(void)
{
  auto * bp = new Derived;
  int i = bp;  // the error here tells us what type bp is
}
```

The error message for the invalid definition of `i` will be something like  `invalid conversion from 'Derived*' to 'int'`.  This tells us that the compiler figured out that `auto` is actually `Derived`, and it did it at compile time, not run time.

Moving on, to answer the second part of your question: you were wondering why `bp->show()` resolved to `Derived::show` instead of `Base::show` when you removed the `virtual` keyword.  The answer is simple: the compiler knows that the type of `bp` is `Derived *`, so when you try to call `show`, it will find `Derived::show` and use that.  There is nothing magical or mysterious going on there.

Now, if you want to cast `bp` to a pointer of type `Base *` and then call `show()` on that pointer, that is the case where you have use virtual functions if you want your program to use `Derived::show` instead of `Base::show`.